# Is the stripes framework dead? Anyone using it?

Tags: java, stripes

I am a big fan of the http://www.stripesframework.org and using it heavily for my projects. However the project seems to be dead. It is not possible to register to the website anymore (no license) and I couldnt contact any of the administrators. Also the mailing-list is not available.

Is anyone aware of the status of the project?

It would be a pity if it was dead as I think it is one of the most elegant frameworks for java web development.

Comment: I had an interview a few months back where the company had just decided to use Stripes as their development framework over Spring.

Comment: @Mark: I'm guessing you didn't take the job

Comment: I had a major stripes project three years ago. It was great fun; very easy, fast and reliable. But since then I learned Wicket and Spring MVC and sorry: they both rock a lot more than Stripes does.

Comment: The evaluation process they used was to give each framework to a trainee programmer, and see who was quicker to implement a multi-page form.... It's got to be better than tossing a coin, right?

Comment: Wicket and Spring MVC are very different frameworks than Stripes. It all depends on what you want in a framework. All are very capable though.

Answer (score 11):

We're using the Stripes Framework on a large Java project. The Stripes project is actually very active. 1.5.4 should be out soon, and the [mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.stripes.user) is where most of the communication takes place.

The website is pretty old, but if the #1 failure of the framework is in marketing itself I don't think that's the worst thing that could be wrong with it. If you'd like to contribute by helping out with a site redesign the planning is going on now.

The mailing list is a great place for questions, and the irc channel #stripes on freenode is pretty active during business hours.

The framework does what it's intended to do very well. There is discussion on new features, but I think a lot of people are happily using it as it is.

Just to note we use Stripes *with* Spring for dependency injection it works very well.

Comment: Stripes 1.5.4 Released, November 9, 2010

Answer (score 5):

*Not at all, The Stripes Framework is activly developed and the mailing list is very active. Information how to subscribe to the **very active** [Stripes mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.stripes.user) can be found here:*

http://www.stripesframework.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=511

*Or go directly to the **[Stripes mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.stripes.user)** @ gmane.org:*

http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.stripes.user

Comment: and now, after a year, they still have 1.5.6

Comment: Uh?! Stripes 1.5.6. was released March 14, 2011...

Comment: yes, it's a current (June 20) release

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, the last released versions were: Stripes 1.5.6 (Mar 2011), Stripes 1.5.5 (Jan 2011), Stripes 1.5.4  (Nov 2010).

Answer (score 2):

Stripes is the main Java web framework choosen in the company i'm actually working in.

It is used on many websites here, including medium sized projects like the french Renault and SFR websites (both ~40 people teams).
Everybody here quite like this framework that integrates nicely with Spring (IoC, Security).

As ScArcher2 said, you can come to the IRC channel #stripes on freebode, it's active with an average of 15 people here (mostly USA business hoursi noticed), including Frederic Daoud who wrote the Stripes book and Ben Gunter, Stripes commiter, and some other people that will be able to give you some advises or friendly discussions.

Stripes documentation is not exhaustive (imho) but it's easy to look at the framework's code and see how it works internally. However if you need help to do something you will find that on the irc channel

The bug fixes comes relatively fast, not like some other projects like Hibernate where some bugs can remain for many years.

Btw if you really like simple Java web frameworks, you should also take a look at Play!

Comment: hi @Sebastien Lorder any news since then? are you still using this framework today? thanks.

Comment: no I'm not using Java anymore

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. Stripes is also one of the best framework in java. Unfortunately some people have no knowledge on this frame work. so that they are using struts ..etc.....Coming days most of the companies used this framework.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.stripesframework.org/jira/browse/STS?report=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:roadmap-panel

Still alive I believe.  1.5.3 just made it into maven central, and they're working on 1.6.

They sure could do a better job of updating their main site though.